# How can we pass a list of JSON object as JSON string in a BDD feature file in Java

Tags: java, json, spring, bdd

Below is my feature file.

**Scenario 1**: Getting all `AppsCount`

When we request for all apps then we get 4 apps and the application list is sent json form:

```
"[
  { '_id' : 'app1', 'Name' : 'App 1', 'Type' : 1, 'Rules' : [ { '_id' : 'Rule1', 'FilterCriteria' : 8 }, { '_id' : 'Rule2', 'FilterCriteria' : 4 } ], 'Email' : 'test@dell.com', 'IsSlackEnabled' : false, 'IsEmailEnabled' : true, 'IsSMSEnabled' : false, 'IsPhoneEnabled' : false, 'IsNonProdEnabled' : false, 'CreatedBy' : 'test@dell.com' },
  { '_id' : 'app2', 'Name' : 'App 2', 'Type' : 2, 'Rules' : [ { '_id' : 'Rule3', 'FilterCriteria' : 8 } ], 'Email' : 'test1@dell.com', 'IsSlackEnabled' : true, 'SlackChannel' : 'testChannel', 'IsEmailEnabled' : false, 'IsSMSEnabled' : false, 'IsPhoneEnabled' : true, 'IsNonProdEnabled' : false, 'CreatedBy' : 'test1@dell.com' },
  { '_id' : 'app3', 'Name' : 'App 3', 'Type' : 3, 'Rules' : [ { '_id' : 'Rule4', 'FilterCriteria' : 7 } ], 'Email' : 'test3@dell.com', 'IsSlackEnabled' : true, 'IsEmailEnabled' : false, 'SlackChannel' : 'testChannel2', 'IsSMSEnabled' : true, 'IsPhoneEnabled' : false, 'IsNonProdEnabled' : false, 'CreatedBy' : 'test3@dell.com' },
  { '_id' : 'app4', 'Name' : 'App 4', 'Type' : 1, 'Rules' : [], 'Email' : 'test4@dell.com', 'IsSlackEnabled' : false, 'IsEmailEnabled' : false, 'IsSMSEnabled' : false, 'IsPhoneEnabled' : true, 'IsNonProdEnabled' : false, 'CreatedBy' : 'test4@dell.com' }
]"
```

But this is giving issue, as we need double quotes when writing a json string

So I tried the below feature file.

**Scenario 2**: Getting all `AppsCount`

When we request for All Apps then we get 4 apps and the application list is sent json form:

```
"[
  { "_id" : "app1", "Name" : "App 1", "Type" : 1, "Rules" : [{ "_id" : "Rule1", "FilterCriteria" : 8 }, { "_id" : "Rule2", "FilterCriteria" : 4 } ], "Email" : "test@dell.com", "IsSlackEnabled" : false, "IsEmailEnabled" : true, "IsSMSEnabled" : false, "IsPhoneEnabled" : false, "IsNonProdEnabled" : false, "CreatedBy" : "test@dell.com" },
  { "_id" : "app2", "Name" : "App 2", "Type" : 2, "Rules" : [ { "_id" : "Rule3", "FilterCriteria" : 8 } ], "Email" : "test1@dell.com", "IsSlackEnabled" : true, "SlackChannel" : "testChannel", "IsEmailEnabled" : false, "IsSMSEnabled" : false, "IsPhoneEnabled" : true, "IsNonProdEnabled" : false, "CreatedBy" : "test1@dell.com" },
  { "_id" : "app3", "Name" : "App 3", "Type" : 3, "Rules" : [ { "_id" : "Rule4", "FilterCriteria" : 7 } ], "Email" : "test3@dell.com", "IsSlackEnabled" : true, "IsEmailEnabled" : false, "SlackChannel" : "testChannel2", "IsSMSEnabled" : true, "IsPhoneEnabled" : false, "IsNonProdEnabled" : false, "CreatedBy" : "test3@dell.com" },
  { "_id" : "app4", "Name" : "App 4", "Type" : 1, "Rules" : [], "Email" : "test4@dell.com", "IsSlackEnabled" : false, "IsEmailEnabled" : false, "IsSMSEnabled" : false, "IsPhoneEnabled" : true, "IsNonProdEnabled" : false, "CreatedBy" : "test4@dell.com" }
] "
```

But when creating a step definition, it comes out with each field's value coming as it's own argument.

I am aware of the

```
| field1 | field2 | 
| value1 | value2 |
```

solution, but my data is too huge for that and was wondering, if there is a way to pass JSON string directly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file text.json ..and put json input in the file .. place this file in class path..

IN feature file place the file name in this case- text.json..

in class file stepdef  read the filename.... look for the this file in class path..

laod this file using clasloader and use objectmapper to map this json.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. I was actually pushing the application to PCF, so had issues regarding file location, but resolved it eventually using other threads. Tried to upvote, but have low reputation :(